# Android Login input to be send via HttpGet JSON to server and return list of user profile information

Tags: java, android, json, authentication, android-asynctask

I have login window, where I want to get user information to the next window and share only the username. I both stored password and username in the database and I want to get array result. Here is my code. 2 EditText where i have to get their values and pass them via json. The link I request is ..../userprofiles?username=. so, when I type the username I have to receive basic info. 
in JSON will be like this:

```
{
   "content": [   {
      "id": 4,
      "email": "email@domain.com",
      "password": "this_will_not_be_set",
      "firstName": "John",
      "phoneNumber": "11223344",
      "username": "newuser",
      "birthDate": 1394204315000,
      "gender": "Male",
      "blacklistedDate": null,
      "userPicture": "Oik=",
      "blacklisted": false
   }],
   "size": 25,
   "number": 0,
   "sort": null,
   "totalPages": 1,
   "numberOfElements": 1,
   "totalElements": 1,
   "lastPage": true,
   "firstPage": true
}
```

and my Android code is:

```
public static String GET(String url) {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = "";
    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // make GET request to the give URL
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(url));

        // receive response as inputStream
        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

        // convert inputstream to string
        if (inputStream != null)
            result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
        else
            result = "Did not work!";

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    return result;
}

private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        return GET(urls[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);

            String str = "";

            JSONArray jArr = json.getJSONArray("content");

            str += "username: " + jArr.getJSONObject(0).getString("username");
            str += "password: " + jArr.getJSONObject(0).getString("password");
            usernameEditText.setText(str);
            passwordEditText.setText(str);
            //etResponse.setText(json.toString(1));

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated! TNX in advance!

Comment: the code looks good. What's the issue?

Comment: Here it is|:(http://i106.photobucket.com/albums/m265/Mihaela15/warning.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JumboJey

You can use the following code for the get the result from the http connection

download the follwoing jar file from the link

https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/raw/master/releases/android-async-http-1.4.4.jar

put jar into lib folder and add follwing code

```
import com.loopj.android.http.*;

AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get("your url", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response) {
            System.out.println(response);
          try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray jArr = json.getJSONArray("content");
           if(jArr.length>0)
           {
                 JSONObject jobj =jArr.getJSONObject(0);
                 String username=jobj.getString("username");
                 String pass=jobj.getString("password");
                 usernameEditText.setText(str);
                passwordEditText.setText(str);
           }
       } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    });
```

Comment: I havre tried loopj, somehow i didnt get any response from it. Where do  i have to useb String username and String pass? from ur example?

Comment: I fix it, I needed to make a new string to get usernameEditText to read the input that I type and to pass it to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

you can try folliwing example for the your json object

```
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    String jsonstr = "{\n   \"content\": [   {\n      \"id\": 4,\n      \"email\": \"email@domain.com\",\n      \"password\": \"this_will_not_be_set\",\n      \"firstName\": \"John\",\n      \"phoneNumber\": \"11223344\",\n      \"username\": \"newuser\",\n      \"birthDate\": 1394204315000,\n      \"gender\": \"Male\",\n      \"blacklistedDate\": null,\n      \"userPicture\": \"Oik=\",\n      \"blacklisted\": false\n   }],\n   \"size\": 25,\n   \"number\": 0,\n   \"sort\": null,\n   \"totalPages\": 1,\n   \"numberOfElements\": 1,\n   \"totalElements\": 1,\n   \"lastPage\": true,\n   \"firstPage\": true\n}";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        TextView txt1 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView txtusername = (TextView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TextView txtpass = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonstr);
            JSONArray jArr = json.getJSONArray("content");
            if (jArr.length() > 0) {
                JSONObject jobj = jArr.getJSONObject(0);
                String username = jobj.getString("username");
                String pass = jobj.getString("password");
                txtusername.setText(username);
                txtpass.setText(pass);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}