# How to get json from server API by android

Tags: android, json

```
public class LiveNote extends Fragment {
    //public static final String ARG_PAGER_NUMBER = "page_number";
       private String JSONString;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saBundle){
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.livenote, container, false);
//        URL url = new URL("http://congress-text-live.herokuapp.com/json/");

        //Thread
        new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
                public void run()
                {
try
{

String uri = "http://congress-text-live.herokuapp.com/json/";

HttpClient mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet mHttpGet = new HttpGet(uri);
HttpResponse mHttpResponse = mHttpClient.execute(mHttpGet);
System.out.println(mHttpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
//HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK is 200 
if(mHttpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK )
    {
//API return json
String mJsonText = EntityUtils.toString(mHttpResponse.getEntity());
//get json
String mTitle = new JSONObject(new JSONObject(mJsonText).getString("latest")).getString("content");
Log.d("d",mTitle);

    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Log.d("d","error");

}
                }
        }).start();

    //  dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(
    //          ARG_PAGER_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

[image]

Here is Log

```
HttpURLConnection == 200
```

but print error?

So `mHttpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK` ?

How can I let parsing normally?

Updating, sorry, I set wrong with key value on json, thanks for response.

Comment: Are you using apache commons for the HttpClient?

Comment: Add this Lines into your `catch` block and post the output: `Log.e("UnsupportedEncodingException", e.toString());` `e.printStackTrace();`

Comment: Ymow Wu


The above same quesiton is discuss here

[How to get json from server API by android][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528789/android-login-input-to-be-send-via-httpget-json-to-server-and-return-list-of-use/22529973#22529973